# how to change active class dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

The error is at ul-> li -> a ng-click.
The class active is not changing when i clicked. 
This is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Talent Exhibition</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="bower_components/angular-ui-   router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app.css"/>
</head>
<body ng-app="talent">
    <div ng-controller="navbarmenuController">
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-brand">
                <a href="index.html">Talent Exhibition</a>
            </div>
            <div ng-controller="navbarformcontroller">
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" ng-submit="loginuser()">
                    <input type="email" ng-model="user.username" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" required>
                    <input type="password" ng-model="user.password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" required>
                    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Login</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid" id="sidebar">
        <div class="row" ng-controller="headercontroller as panel">
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 hidden-xs jumbotron">
                <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                    <li ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-class="{active : panel.isselected({{tab.id}})}"><a ng-click="panel.selecttab({{tab.id}})" ui-sref="{{tab.name}}">{{tab.name}}</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main" id="main" ui-view></div>
        </div>

    </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my app.js is

```
talent.controller('headercontroller', function (){
    this.tab = 1;

    this.selecttab = function (setTab){
        this.tab = setTab;
    };

    this.isselected = function (checkTab){
        return this.tab === checkTab;
    };
});
```

and my error details are

> Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'tab.id' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 19 of         the expression [panel.selecttab({{tab.id}})] starting at [tab.id}})].
>   (`http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.23/$parse/syntax?p0=tab.id&p1=is%20unexpected%2C%20expecting%20%5B%3A%5D&p2=19&p3=panel.selecttab(%7B%7Btab.id%7D%7D)&p4=tab.id%7D%7D`)
>       at (`http://localhost:63342/Talent/bower_components/angular/angular.js:78:12`)
>       at Parser.throwError (`http://localhost:63342/Talent/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10534:11`)
>       at Parser.consume (`http://localhost:63342/Talent/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10568:12`)
>       at Parser.object (`http://localhost:63342/Talent/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10885:14`)
>       at Parser.primary (`http://localhost:63342/Talent/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10504:22`)
>       at Parser.unary (`http://localhost:63342/Talent/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10757:19`)
>       at Parser.multiplicative (`http://localhost:63342/Talent/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10740:21`)
>      at Parser.additive (`http://localhost:63342/Talent/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10731:21`)
>      at Parser.relational (`http://localhost:63342/Talent/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10722:21`)
>       at Parser.equality (`http://localhost:63342/Talent/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10713:21`) > 
>     (anonymous function)    angular.js:10061
>     (anonymous function)    angular.js:7357
>     applyDirectivesToNode   angular.js:6473
>     compileNodes    angular.js:6036
>     compileNodes    angular.js:6048
>     compile angular.js:5969
>     applyDirectivesToNode   angular.js:6379
>     compileNodes    angular.js:6036
>     compileNodes    angular.js:6048
>     compileNodes    angular.js:6048
>     compileNodes    angular.js:6048
>     compileNodes    angular.js:6048
>     compileNodes    angular.js:6048
>     compileNodes    angular.js:6048
>     compile angular.js:5969
>     (anonymous function)    angular.js:1449
>     Scope.$eval angular.js:12673
>     Scope.$apply    angular.js:12771
>     (anonymous function)    angular.js:1447
>     invoke  angular.js:3966
>     doBootstrap angular.js:1445
>     bootstrap   angular.js:1459
>     angularInit angular.js:1368
>     (anonymous function)    angular.js:21949
>     trigger angular.js:2573
>     (anonymous function)    angular.js:2853
>     forEach angular.js:325
>     eventHandler    angular.js:2852"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your handlebars in your `ng-click` directive are superfluous. Try it without them:

```
<a ng-click="panel.selecttab(tab.id)" ui-sref="{{tab.name}}">{{tab.name}}</a>
```

Generally you only need the curly braces if you're binding to values in the bare markup, not in a directive.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/templates

Which means you probably don't want them in your `ui-sref` directive either:

```
<a ng-click="panel.selecttab(tab.id)" ui-sref="tab.name">{{tab.name}}</a>
```